# Static Class Variables ES6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux

Is it a good idea to use static properties in ES6. Some of my colleagues believe that it is a bad idea, but I did not get a good explanation as to why it was so.

I am building a ReactJs application, and I use redux wherever necessary, however, when I want to share some data with all the components in the app, can I use static class properties?

In my case it's we want to share the value of a variable called *ThemeName* across all components. Note that the components do not listen to changes to this variable. It just takes the value of the variable when it loads.

It actually works without any issues, yet somehow I have this feeling that it could be anti patten, can someone please explain the issue here, if any?

Comment: Hi! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask), [*What types of questions should I avoid asking?*](/help/dont-ask), and [*What topics can I ask about here?*](/help/on-topic) This is too opinion-based for SO's format. The close vote reason is *"Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise."*

Comment: *"Some of my colleagues believe that it is a bad idea..."* I suggest asking them why they think it's a bad idea, and whether they have further resources backing that view they can point you at.

Comment: I did, but as I stated, I did not get a proper explanation from them, that is why I thought of looking for an answer here.

Comment: In general, I don't trust advice when the person giving it can't point to specific reasons for it. :-)

Comment: Can you think of a use-case where using either would be a bad idea?  No language/design is *perfect*.  Programming is just an exercise of teasing order out of chaos; sometimes bits of that chaos will make its way through and show up in your code.  Nothing you can do about it at that point except adapt and change.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with storing *constants* as static properties. As soon as you are going to dynamically *load* that data though, you're venturing into a grey area.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a good idea to use static properties *with React* for a few reasons:

- Class properties aren't tapped into the React's lifecycle, so unless these properties are never, ever going to change, static properties are going to be too inflexible.
- React itself if moving away from classes in general, so if you are new to React I would recommend not using classes at all. You can read more about the motivation behind this in the [official React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html#classes-confuse-both-people-and-machines)
- React cooperates with other mechanisms for accomplishing what you are trying to accomplish, whether that be Redux, or [Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)